# DNS leak for non-existent domains when using OpenVPN on a Windows client

Tags: dns, openvpn, dnsmasq, captive-portal, pihole

I have a Windows client connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Atheros Wireless Network Adapter
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.110(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

The Wi-Fi hotspot has its own DNS (as seen above) which resolves any NXDOMAIN to an advertising 'search page' - this is unwanted behavior. This malicious DNS server is initially needed to get past the Wi-Fi's captive portal, so I can't just set a static DNS to override it.

I then connect to my home network using OpenVPN. Server configuration:

```
server 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
proto udp
dev tun21
push "route 10.1.0.0 255.255.254.0"    (my home IP subnet)
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN local"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.0.8"
client-to-client
```

The OpenVPN server is on `10.1.0.1`, my home gateway.

The DNS server is pihole on `10.1.0.8`.

Client configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote mydynip.net
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
dhcp-option DNS 10.1.0.8    (I tried adding this for redundancy, has no effect)
```

The OpenVPN connection succeeds:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.6(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.5
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.0.8
```

Now, if the Windows client looks up a domain that *does* exist, everything works as it should. For example:

```
>ping mypc.local
Pinging mypc.local [10.1.0.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.1.0.2: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=127
...
```

... and I see this in the pihole query log (all normal):

```
Time            Type  Domain      Client         Status         Reply
2019-07-16...   A     mypc.local  gateway.local  OK (forwarded) IP (2.5ms)
```

However, If I look up a nonexistent domain, even with the `.local` prefix, the domain resolves to an advertising page(!) :

```
>ping nonexist.local
Pinging nonexist.local [198.xx.xx.xx (!!!)] with 32 bytes of data:
...
```

The query *does* pass though the pihole first:

```
Time            Type  Domain          Client         Status         Reply
2019-07-16...   A     nonexist.local  gateway.local  OK (forwarded) NXDOMAIN (2.5ms)
```

...but it seems that upon receipt of NXDOMAIN the Windows client then tries the Wi-Fi hotspot's malicious DNS server! How do I stop this behavior?

---

Stuff I tried:
Adding `redirect-gateway def1` to the client OpenVPN config nicely redirects all traffic through the VPN, but has *no* effect at all on the DNS behavior depicted above. It effectively makes my home gateway `(gateway.local)` connect to the advertising 'search page' and forward it to the Windows client through the OpenVPN tunnel. At this point, though, the DNS query has already been leaked to the Wi-Fi hotspot's DNS server.

---

Here's what looks like a possible solution:

If I have the Windows client look up a domain that is *blocked* on the pihole, Windows does not forward the request to the Wi-Fi hotspot's DNS:

```
>ping googletagservices.com
Ping request could not find host...
```

...in pihole query log:

```
Time            Type  Domain      Client         Status             Reply
2019-07-16...   A     goo....com  gateway.local  Blocked (gravity)  - (0.5ms)
```

This is because the pihole resolves the address to `0.0.0.0` and the Windows client seems satisfied with that.

The problem is, how do I get pihole to reply to all nonexistent domains with `0.0.0.0` rather than `NXDOMAIN`? I couldn't find any option in dnsmasq that would do that...

Answer (score 1):

Oops, a few more minutes of searching and I would have found it!

Adding `block-outside-dns` to the OpenVPN client configuration fixes this behavior.